# Count on curdate() in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a `user_entry` table which contains a `date` field. data type is datetime.
data base is mysql.
I want a count of current date and current month and all data of current date.

How can I get this?

I tried below query but it's not working.

```
select * from table 
where DATE(date) = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date FROM `test` WHERE date = CURDATE()
```

or

```
SELECT date FROM `test` WHERE date = DATE('2016-04-04')
```

it's work.
if you want the number of matches:

```
SELECT COUNT(date) from test WHERE date = CURDATE()
```

What is the data type of field 'date'?
To obtain the DAY/MONTH you can use the corresponding functions

```
SELECT MONTH(date), DAY(date) from test
```

Moreover, you can use groups to create a complete report

```
SELECT COUNT(date), date from test GROUP BY DAY(date), MONTH(date)
```

Comment: data type of date field is datetime

Comment: try 
select * from user_entry where DATE(`date`) = CURDATE()

Answer (score 0):

i used below query and it works for me.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `user_entry` 
WHERE DATE( DATE ) = DATE( NOW( ) )
```